# WordPress how to add own PHP code made up of multiple files and an imported package?

Tags: php, database, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I want to add a table to a page that changes depending on a selection (button) on that same page, that also uses a HTML grabber package that I've imported to my vendor directory in the project. Is there any way to add this code to WordPress?

I've tried running my site locally through Xampp but the only way to edit pages is through the database and I can only add lines of HTML. I expected WordPress to have a folder structure with a file for each page where I could simply add my PHP code and the imported package to a vendor folder. Now I'm not sure it is possible.I've tried running my site locally through Xampp but the only way to edit pages is through the database and I can only add lines of HTML.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: _"I expected WordPress to have a folder structure with a file for each page"_ - no, that is not how it works. WP is not a static site generator. You'll need to look deeper into how WP's templating system works. https://codex.wordpress.org/Stepping_into_Templates, https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/